# mysql select from one or another table

Tags: mysql, if-statement

Thanks, for your help, I posted a simplified version of my problem but I really didn't understand how to apply the left join in the big one that is this:

```
SELECT d.type, 
       d.item , 
       if(d.type='I', a.name, b.name) as name, 
       if(d.type='I', c.price,0) as price, 
       if(d.type='I',if(d.taxes='yes', 
       (c.priceWithTax*d.weight), (c.price*d.weight)),0) as totalprice 
  FROM d 
inner join a on d.item=a.id 
inner join c on d.item=c.item
     where c.sede =1
```

The problem is that when d.type='I' I need the items from table a, but if d.type='S' I need the items from table B, the prices are on table c.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you please make your question more clear? Perhaps a real-world example might help?

Comment: I believe he is asking how he can join on table C only if b.col2 = apple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select
  a.col1,
  b.col1,
  coalesce(c.col1,0)
from a inner join b on a.col0=b.col1
  left outer join c on b.col2='apple' and c.col1=b.col0
```

Things to learn:

- [outer joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)
- function [`COALESCE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce)
- use single-quotes for string literals in SQL, not double-quotes

---

> I have an rawFood table, a cookedFood table and a Menu table and the menu table has things from both, rawFood and cookedFood, thats why I need to join that way

You need to have a single `food` table, and give it a column that notes the difference between raw and cooked food.

Comment: Thanks, for your help, I posted a simplified version of my problem but I really didn't understand how to apply the left join in the big one that is this:

SELECT d.type, d.item , if(d.type='I', a.name, b.name) as name, if(d.type='I', c.price,0) as price, if(d.type='I',if(d.taxes='yes', (c.priceWithTax*d.weight), (c.price*d.weight)),0) as totalprice FROM d inner join a on d.item=a.id inner join c on d.item=c.item where c.sede =1 

The problem is that when d.type='I' I need the items from table a, but if d.type='S' I need the items from table B, the prices are on table c.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

If you need something like this, that's clearly indicates that your database structure is wrong.
It should be **one** table, and your query become plain and easy.

Comment: thanks for the answer Col. Shrapnel, the problem is that I have an rawFood table, a cookedFood table and a Menu table and the menu table has things from both, rawFood and cookedFood, thats why I need to join that way

Comment: @notforever but it must be one table, with a field named "raw" (or "cooked" - no matter). That's very basic database rule. All similar data should be in one table. Or you'll be in constant troubles like this one

Answer (score 0):

You can use a left join

```
select
    a.col1,
    b.col1,
    ifnull(c.col1,0)
from a 
    inner join b on a.col0=b.col1
    left join c on (c.col1 = b.col0 and b.col2="apple")
where
    b.col2 != "apple" or (b.col2 = "apple" and c.col1 is not null)
```

Comment: Thanks, for your help, I posted a simplified version of my problem but I really didn't understand how to apply the left join in the big one that is this:

SELECT d.type, d.item , if(d.type='I', a.name, b.name) as name, if(d.type='I', c.price,0) as price, if(d.type='I',if(d.taxes='yes', (c.priceWithTax*d.weight), (c.price*d.weight)),0) as totalprice FROM d inner join a on d.item=a.id inner join c on d.item=c.item where c.sede =1

The problem is that when d.type='I' I need the items from table a, but if d.type='S' I need the items from table B, the prices are on table c.

Thank you very much.